About R- squared in random forest regression
Suppose I have three features [x1, x2, x3] and a target variable y1 for use in a Random Forest regression model. I have two datasets: df1, which contains only the relevant features [x1, x2, x3], and df2, which includes additional irrelevant columns (e.g., x4, x5) alongside [x1, x2, x3].
Now, I want to run the Random Forest regression using only the features [x1, x2, x3] and target y1 for both df1 and df2 as follows.
The dataset is split into training and testing sets using the train_test_split function. The training set is used to fit the RandomForestRegressor model, and the testing set is used to evaluate the model's performance. After the model is trained on the training data (X_train, y_train), predictions are made on the test set (X_test).
The $R^2$ score is calculated as an out-of-sample measure of performance by comparing the predictions on the test set (y_pred) with the actual test set values (y_test) using the r2_score function.
Will the $R^2$ values be the same for the two datasets? Why or why not?

Welcome to Cross Validated! How are you calculating $R^2?$ Are you calculating an in-sample or out-of-sample measure of performance?

the  R2 score is calculated as an out-of-sample measure of performance. Here's how it's done:
The dataset is split into training and testing sets using the train_test_split function. The training set is used to fit the RandomForestRegressor model, and the testing set is used to evaluate the model's performance.
After the model is trained on the training data (X_train, y_train), predictions are made on the test set (X_test).
The R 2  score is calculated by comparing the predictions on the test set (y_pred) with the actual test set values (y_test) using the r2_score function

From the comments

the R2 score is calculated as an out-of-sample measure of performance. Here's how it's done: The dataset is split into training and testing sets using the train_test_split function. The training set is used to fit the RandomForestRegressor model, and the testing set is used to evaluate the model's performance. After the model is trained on the training data (X_train, y_train), predictions are made on the test set (X_test). The R 2 score is calculated by comparing the predictions on the test set (y_pred) with the actual test set values (y_test) using the r2_score function

The r2_score function you call is a monotonic transformation of the mean squared error, discussed here with the equation written down along with commentary about the calculation and possible difficulties in its motivation. Nonetheless, that calculation is a monotonic (decreasing) transformation of mean squared error.
Thus, your question can be rephrased as asking if the out-of-sample mean squared error must increase when you add irrelevant features, and the answer is an emphatic no. Your model has a good chance of overfitting to those irrelevant features, harming out-of-sample performance.
